# How to concatenate several file with * in the path using xargs or parallel

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, xargs, gnu-parallel

I have a command that fetch a path to a file for each line in a CSV file :

```
awk -F, 'NR>0 {print "/mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/" $2 "_*/dragen-covidseq/" $1 "_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa"}' input.csv
```

Example of the input.csv file :

```
2071404446,RUN111
2071405093,RUN111
2071405134,RUN111
```

Example of verbose after this command :

```
/mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_*/dragen-covidseq/2071404446_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa
/mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_*/dragen-covidseq/2071405093_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa
/mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_*/dragen-covidseq/2071405134_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa
```

And now I want to concatenate all the content of the different file into one file. I tried simple pipe command like :

```
awk -F, 'NR>0 {print "/mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/" $2 "_*/dragen-covidseq/" $1 "_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa"}' input.csv | xargs cat > output.fasta
```

But I have the "no such file or directory" error because it seems that `xargs` interpret `*` as a character instead of as wildcards. For information, aside from  `*`, I don't have space or any spacial character in my path.

Do you have an idea how to do that ?

Comment: Please show a few lines of your input file and copy&paste the full error message. Are the `*` intended as wildcards or do the file and directory names contain `*` characters? The file name globbing is done by the shell. If you pass a file name pattern that contains e.g. `*` to `xargs` it will use it as a literal file name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The `*` are intended as wildcards and that exactly my question ; how to do my concatenation with a bash command that understand my path ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this clarification and show a few lines of your input file. Please tell us if your input fields can contain spaces or other characters that may have special meaning for the shell.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: I re-edited my post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand the `*` characters as shell glob characters (wildcards) you have to pass them to a program that will do this, e.g. to a shell.

Assuming that the fields of the input file do not contain other characters that have a special meaning for the shell, you can try (1):

```
awk -F, 'NR>0 {print "cat /mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/" $2 "_*/dragen-covidseq/" $1 "_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa"}' input.csv | sh > output.fasta
```

The `awk` command prints commands like `cat /path/with/wildcards/to/some/file` which are piped to a shell for interpretation. If you want to avoid running a separate `cat` process for every file you can have the shell print the file names and pass this to `xargs` (2):

```
awk -F, 'NR>0 {print "echo /mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/" $2 "_*/dragen-covidseq/" $1 "_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa"}' input.csv | sh | xargs cat > output.fasta
```

---

When I run the `awk` command from (1) with the input file as shown in the question, the output of the `awk` command is

```
cat /mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_*/dragen-covidseq/2071404446_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa
cat /mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_*/dragen-covidseq/2071405093_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa
cat /mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_*/dragen-covidseq/2071405134_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa
```

Note that the output lines start with **`cat`** (in contrast to the `awk` command in the question).

I cannot test the expansion of the `*` characters by the shell because I don't have any files that would match the pattern.

The `awk` command from (2) will create similar output, but with `echo` instead of `cat`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunatly it doesn't work. It seems to perform a cat for each line of each file

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "It seems to perform a `cat` *for each line of each file*"? The output of the `awk` command should be lines like `cat /mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_*/dragen-covidseq/2071404446_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa` or `echo /mnt/d... ...e/RUN111_*/dragen-covidseq/2071404446_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa` respectively. In the first case, the shell would run a `cat` process for every individual file, in the second case it will print the expanded file names using the `echo` builtin.

Comment: As an example, here is the last line of the verbose : /mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_211228_NL500139_0591_AHYKYNBGXK/dragen-covidseq/2071405134_485619862_ds.75583deeeced4b32a48b3f77b8ea6c9d/consensus/2071405134.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa: 428: /mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/RUN111_211228_NL500139_0591_AHYKYNBGXK/dragen-covidseq/2071405134_485619862_ds.75583deeeced4b32a48b3f77b8ea6c9d/consensus/2071405134.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa: TCCCCATGTGATTTTAATAGCTTCTTAGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN: not found

Comment: @nstatam The error message looks like you passed the contents of some of your files to a shell, not the `cat /some/of/your/file/patterns` created by my command. Did you run *my* `awk` command or did you do something based on the output of *your* `awk` command?

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are no special shell characters in `$base` and `$fa_pattern` this should work:

```
base=/mnt/datagenetique/ANALYSIS/Infectiologie/COVID-WGS/Analyse/
fa_pattern=_*_ds*/consensus/*.consensus_hard_masked_sequence.fa

# Generate one file per pattern
cat input.csv |
  parallel --colsep , eval cat $base/{2}_*/dragen-covidseq/{1}$fa_pattern '>' {1}.fa

# Put everything in a single file
cat input.csv |
  parallel --colsep , eval cat $base/{2}_*/dragen-covidseq/{1}$fa_pattern > all.fa

# This may be faster
cat input.csv |
  parallel --colsep , -uj1 eval cat $base/{2}_*/dragen-covidseq/{1}$fa_pattern > all2.fa
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the shell interpret input data at your own risk, of course, but that is what you're asking for help to do so:

```
$ echo first > foolbar
$ echo second > foo\*bar

$ cat $(awk 'BEGIN{print "foo*bar"}')
second
first
```

The above assumes the list of arguments to `cat` won't exceed the shells max args length, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185165/1745001. Alternatively:

```
$ while IFS= read -r file; do cat $file; done < <(awk 'BEGIN{print "foo*bar"}')
second
first
```